# What database Palo OLAP server handles?

Tags: olap, business-intelligence, olap-cube

I was wondering what Palo OLAP Server handles as input Database ?

Does someone know where I can find a list of the input Database supported ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like any standard relational database through JDBC or flat files.  Here's what it says on the [jedox website](http://www.jedox.com/en/products/Palo-Suite/palo-ETL-Server.html).

Answer (score 1):

Palo has lots of options for inputs, including relational databases.  I don't know if anyone has made a list of supported databases, but I would not worry about being able to use a specific one - because you always have the option of writing a SQL statement to extract your data into a flat file and then loading the flat file into Palo.